# Changing Currency on Site

Tags: database

I will be selling products on my site in ***GBP***, however I would like an option for my customers to change currency to ***dollars*** and ***euros***. This I know how to do but is there anyway to automatically fetch the data (currency rates) without manually changing it each day.

Also.
To avoid people tampering with the data on ***PayPal***,which means that people can change the price to 1p. I put a security function:

> if the price = fixed price then transaction approved.

However as the currency well keep changing is there anyway to get around that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a tricky one.

If you accept payment in other currencies, you firstly have to show the price in that currency; this is not available as a feed or web service from PayPal (as far as I know). There are other feeds which provide this (Google is your friend - "currency conversion feed"), but they will never be exactly the same as PayPal.

The second issue is that - once you have taken payment in that currency - you don't know exactly how much you're going to get back in Pounds - say the sale happens today, but you only withdraw the money next week. The exchange rate could have shifted in that time, making your sale worth less in GBP. This risk could easily eat up your profits - especially in times of financial volatility.

The third issue is that currency conversion costs money - depending on volume and method, somewhere between 2 and 5%.

So, unless you're selling products with a very high margin, I'd be very nervous about taking payment in other currencies unless you can spend in those currencies too; if you can spend the money in foreign currencies, you don't have to pay for the conversion, and you are less exposed to the currency risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can call out to a currency exchange web service.

Comment: Sorry I forogot to say that to avoid people tampering with the data on PayPal which means that people can change the price to 1p I put a security function if the price = fixed price then transaction approved.

However as the currency well keep changing is there anyway to get around that aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking with your bank (whoever is behind your e-commerce site), as they may have a free tool for this.

Here is an example from a bank in New York -- it's a web service that will give you the exchange rate for any given date in xml format: http://www.ny.frb.org/markets/pilotfx.html

There is also the Google Finance API
http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/reference.html

This service is not free (I don't think), but looks pretty slick, and gives A LOT of infmormation via web service: http://www.xignite.com/forex/web-service/2000106.html